# Error when clipping by layer mask

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, error

I'm using QGIS 3.28.5 and I'm having problems trying to crop an INPE image by the layer mask of a vector file in QGIS. When I try, the following error appears:

```
GDAL command output:
ERROR 1: The key Unknown-0 of TIFFTagLocation=0 has count=0, while only 1 is legal.
ERROR 1: The key Unknown-0 of TIFFTagLocation=0 has count=0, while only 1 is legal.
Warning 1: C:/Users/laura/Downloads/09S375ZN/09S375ZN.tif: Apparently corrupt GeoTIFF tags are being ignored.
ERROR 1: Unable to calculate the cutting line bounding box. Cannot find source SRS
The process returned error code 1

The following message appears in the message log pane: 2023-10-04T19:15:42 INFO gdalwarp -overwrite -of GTiff -cutline "C:\Users\laura\Desktop\banco_dados_qgis\Mapas PIBEX\ Vetorizacao_Faz_Urumbeta_Final.shp" -cl Vetorizacao_Faz_Urumbeta_Final -crop_to_cutline C:/Users/laura/Downloads/09S375ZN/09S375ZN.tif C:/Users/laura/Desktop/banco_dados_qgis/arquivos_raster/faz_urumbeta_recortado.tif
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently corrupt GeoTIFF tags?  Maybe include the gdalinfo  output in your answer to rule out corrupt GeoTiff tags?

Comment: can you point us to the INPE image data (online?)